# Different window/body sizes in different browsers

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am implementing a fluid layout, which implies that sizes of elements on screen are computed using percentages rather than hardcoded in pixels.

One thing I've notice is that, on the same screen with maximized window, different browsers simply have different `body` sizes to start with! As a result of that, a same `div` in different browsers will have slightly different sizes as well as positions.

I've tested in Chrome, FF and Safari, and their body sizes when maximized are: 1280 x 702, 1279 x 687, 1280 x 684 respectively. It seems that the main difference is in the height, which might be explained by different designs/positions of the URL bar, tabs, etc?

Is this something a developer just has to live with (especially when using a fluid layout)? If so, is there any remedy to ensure that an element always has exactly the same size in different browser? Or is there something else I've missed which causes such discrepancies?

Answer (score 0):

Using a fluid layout means that your layout must be able to adapt to pretty much any resolution, so the slight differences between maximized browsers on your 1280x768 monitor are the least of your concerns. People have different sized monitors (or phone screens, or tablets), and they don't only view pages maximized. Your layout needs to flow without breaking to match whatever width the person resizes their browser to. This is difficult, which is why fixed width pages with gutters are more popular for simple sites.

P.S. If you're going to be doing web development, you should get a monitor with at least a 1920x1080 resolution. That is what a lot of people are going to be viewing your site at these days, and unless you have a monitor to match, you won't be able to see what it looks like. Plus it will give you way more screen space to work with your code.